# Animations(traslate and alpha) for Drawables drawn on Surfaceview

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas

I am creating a customized view(Restaurant) by extending Surfaceview(following Lunarlander from Android sample projects). I have to draw many drawables and when the user selects them ,they have animate(traslation  and alpha) and eventually disappear. Now I am implementing  this animations manually with drawable.setBounds() and drawable.setAlpha(). Is there any shorter,inbuilt way(like view or property animations for Views) to achieve the same.???